# Using a Boolean param to query Null or Not Null

Tags: sql, postgresql, jpa, spring-data

Background I need a query that will return all the assigned  or unassigned jobs given a set of parameters. I control neither the database nor the params in the URL. Currently the URL sends true if it wants all the assigned jobs and false if it wants unassigned. In the table the column  'assigned' is a foreign key with an ID if assigned and null if not assigned.
My  goal is

```
@Query(Select * from job j where j.location =:loc and j.assigned= :assigned) 
Public List<Job> getJobs(@Param("loc") String location,
                         @Param("assigned ") Boolean assigned);
```

Of course I can just create multiple queries based on whether assigned is true or false. But it was hoping it could be done in one action instead using a Postgres database fyi

Comment: Sorry about formatting had to type on my phone couldn't log onto SO on work computer gonna try to fix it

Comment: So you want to get assigned = NULL if the :assigned param is false? Something like `COALESCE(j.assigned, FALSE) = :assigned`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `CASE` statement in `WHERE` clause:

```
@Query(Select * from job j where j.location =:loc and case when :assigned then j.assigned is not null else j.assigned is null end)
```

[Testing](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=92698157917c3f64a88a36e19b650326)